# Can I use a function defined in the main file from an extension file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The bot I have right now has quite a few functions, and I'm planning on moving several of them to extension files. My question is: if I have a function I defined in the main bot file, can I use it in the command in the extension file? I still do not fully understand how extensions work in discordpy even after reading the documentation so I would appreciate it if someone here could explain it to me.

In my case, I would like to move the `down()` command to an extension, but it uses a function called `downSpam()` defined in the same file. If I move `down()` to an extension, will I still be able to use `downSpam()`?

Example of current code

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= ...)

@bot.command()
async def down(ctx):
    if(ctx.guild.id == myGuildID):
        downSpam.start(ctx)

@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def downSpam(ctx):
    link = imgLink
    await sendPics(ctx, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Comment: If you have utility functions used in several places, put them in their own file (`utilities.py`?), and then import that every place you need them.

Comment: @TimRoberts That helps to solve my problem indeed, but I am still curious as to whether it is possible to do. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Short answer, no.  The functions in your main module are in that module's namespace.  A submodule can't refer to those without importing it, and that causes circular references that are difficult to untangle.  Good programming practice is that each module should be able to operate on its own, without any knowledge of how it got included.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the answer, I'll keep that in mind.